# How do I undo a git commit that made sitewide changes 7 commits earlier

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit

So I thoughtlessly used CodeMaid to reformat my work project. All it did was change the usings and remove blank lines. However the byproduct of it was to change the version dates on all files.

Now the Manager won't let me commit my branch, naturally enough, as all files have now been changed.

Is it possible to remove the one commit and have its changes cascade upwards undoing themselves? Or, as I have started to do, make a new branch below the commit and manually add in every change after it?

Comment: Why not fetch and rebase or merge?  What you describe - removing a commit - is making a new branch and reapplying every change.  Doing it manually is a choice; you could just do a multi way rebase.  But that sounds like more work than just rebasing your local work.

Comment: `git rebase -i`

Comment: ... oh, your local change is heavily modified?  Ya, `git rebase -i origin/master` and delete the codemaid commit (assuming it was one commit).  If it is mixed with other stuff in the same commit, you can edit, revert all but what you intended to do, then commit and continue the rebase.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have been using Azure-devops so my git commands are really minimal. I have the commit ID of the one I want to remove. If I use rebase how do I tell it which commit to rebase from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove the one commit and have its changes cascade upwards undoing themselves?

If you are using the Azure-devops, you could find that the commit Id and select the Revert:

[image]

[image]

It will create a pull request to complete the revert:

After completing the PR, the commit was rolled back.